# Issue in response in struts2

Tags: java, json, jboss, struts2

I am working json with struts2. When i send response to my jsp i am getting extra space in front of my message not creating problem for , How to truncate that space. My code as follows

```
HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
                        response.setContentType("text/plain");           
                    response.getWriter().write(sStatusMessage.trim());
                    response.flushBuffer();
                    response.reset();
```

Above code is my action code , when i reponse to jsp it taking extra space . How to remove that space

My json like this

```
  fnOnDeleting: function (tr, id, fnDeleteRow) {
                       var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
                       jConfirm("Please confirm that you want to delete row " + oSettings.aoColumns[1].sTitle + ' with "' + $("td:first",tr).text() + '"', "Confirm Delete", function (r) {
                               if (r) 
                               {
                                     fnDeleteRow(id);
                               }
                           });
                               return false;
                          },
                       sAddDeleteToolbarSelector: ".dataTables_length"          
                       });
```

Comment: how you sending JSON? are you using S2-Json plugin ?

Comment: What do you mean, "it taking extra space"?

Comment: @DaveNewton i am sending respone ok to but in response it talking extra sapce in front of ok ..

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I also tried with json plugin my action follows like this <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default"><action name="wuser" class="com.canwin.action.WriteDataAction">
<result type="json" name="success"><param name="root">sStatusMessage</param></result></action></package>

Answer (score 0):

I would try making the type JSON for starters:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON